# No sound in HDMI with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, sound, hdmi

When I plug a HDMI tv, I do have the image but not the sound. I already had the pb with ubuntu 14.04 and still have it with ubuntu 18.04.

In ubuntu 14, I tried a lot of solutions I found in forums, but nothing worked. So now I will try to ask some help...

Here is some info :

```
lspci | grep "VGA compatible controller"

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)
```

,

```
lshw -enable pci -class display

*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   produit: GK107M [GeForce GT 650M]
   fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   ressources: irq:35 mémoire:f6000000-f6ffffff mémoire:e0000000-efffffff mémoire:f0000000-f1ffffff portE/S:e000(taille=128) mémoire:f7000000-f707ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   produit: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   fabriquant: Intel Corporation
   identifiant matériel: 2
   information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   ressources: irq:26 mémoire:f7400000-f77fffff mémoire:d0000000-dfffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

,

```
xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 connected 1280x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
1280x768      59.99*+
1920x1080     59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.05    60.00    50.04  
1360x768      60.02  
1280x1024     60.02  
1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00    50.00  
1024x768      85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
800x600       85.06    75.00    72.19    60.32  
720x576       50.00  
720x480       59.94  
640x480       85.01    75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
LVDS-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.01  
1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
1600x1024     60.17  
1400x1050     59.98  
1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
1280x1024     60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1400x900      59.96    59.88  
1280x960      60.00  
1440x810      60.00    59.97  
1368x768      59.88    59.85  
1360x768      59.80    59.96  
1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
1152x864      60.00  
1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
1024x768      60.04    60.00  
960x720       60.00  
928x696       60.05  
896x672       60.01  
1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
960x600       59.93    60.00  
960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
840x525       60.01    59.88  
864x486       59.92    59.57  
800x512       60.17  
700x525       59.98  
800x450       59.95    59.82  
640x512       60.02  
720x450       59.89  
700x450       59.96    59.88  
640x480       60.00    59.94  
720x405       59.51    58.99  
684x384       59.88    59.85  
680x384       59.80    59.96  
640x400       59.88    59.98  
576x432       60.06  
640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
512x384       60.00  
512x288       60.00    59.92  
480x270       59.63    59.82  
400x300       60.32    56.34  
432x243       59.92    59.57  
320x240       60.05  
360x202       59.51    59.13  
320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1280x1024 (0x53) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
1024x768 (0x68) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
800x600 (0x77) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
640x480 (0x86) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
    v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

,

```
lspci | grep -i audio

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

When I go to the sound parameters (with my HDMI tv plugged), I don't have any HDMI out.

Anyone has an idea to fix this problem ?

Tks !

Answer (score 0):

**Try these**

- Check the sound settings
  [image: Sound Settings]

Then

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

open

```
pavucontrol
```

Check the settings

Comment: Hello, thks for your answer. I don't have nvidia showing with `aplay -l`. Here is the result :  `carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0: ALC663 Analog [ALC663 Analog]` and `carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 1: ALC663 Digital [ALC663 Digital]` (while having the HDMI tv plugged)

Comment: I think there is something missing. Try again. Your `lspci | grep "VGA compatible controller"` shows

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)`
`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)` so I think there is no harm in trying maybe `options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=0 probe_mask=0xffff,0xfff2`

Comment: [@jon](https://askubuntu.com/users/608563/jon) please check up the changed answer

Comment: The command to check the sound hardware is not complete. Run `lspci -k | grep -i -A2 audio` which should hopefully show you that a sound driver has been provided by the kernel. Also you don't need pavucontrol unless you want to set up some niche audio arrangements, eg dealing with multi audio inputs.

Comment: I have created a file  /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf and added inside `options snd-hda-intel enable_msi=0 probe_mask=0xffff,0xfff2` but nothing changed... Do I realod something after creating this file ?

Comment: @PaulBenson, the result of your command : `00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
`

Comment: @Vijay I already have pavucontrol installed, but I don't have any HDMI out... And here is my sound parameters : https://framapic.org/ZkaNwHlNnuOW/9HvuPN2VGdjx.png

Comment: It seems that your audio and video chips don't have proper drivers for HDMI output. Needs research. Model etc of your "pb". Display driver.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with those entries in sound.conf, except it may not be the right one for your GPU, and I would do that as last resort. You've shown that you have the standard Linux sound driver support for an Intel sound chip. Next I would follow [these procedures](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) first to retrieve your audio, then [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html).

Comment: Can try `snd-hda-intel enable_msi=0 probe_mask=0xffff` or `snd-hda-intel enable_msi=0 probe_mask=0xffff,0xfff2,0xfff2` or try removing `enable_msi=0` Total 6 options